# How to update activity with onResume() (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, activity-lifecycle

Sorry if this is poor etiquette but I have now re-written my entire question as the original question I asked didn't actually relate to my problem as I have just realised. I am having trouble updating the code in an activity after I return to it. The first activity contains a bunch of imageButtons which relate to levels. When the app is first run only the level one button is enabled. When that button is clicked it sends the user to a new activity where they must spell a set amount of words to unlock the next level. This is the code for my level select activity.

```
public class QuizLevelSelect extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int myLevel;
ImageButton level1, level2, level3, level4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_level_select);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/variane-script.regular.ttf");
    title.setTypeface(custom_font);

    level1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.level1);
    level2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.level2);
    level2.setEnabled(false);
    level3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.level3);
    level3.setEnabled(false);
    level4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.level4);
    level4.setEnabled(false);

    level1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("intVariableName", 1);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    level2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("intVariableName", 2);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    level3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("intVariableName", 3);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Wordbank");
    query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject object : objects){
                myLevel = object.getInt("level");
            }
    });
    if (myLevel == 2){
        level2.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

}

When the level one button is clicked it starts a new activity where the user has to spell a set amount of words (only 1 at the moment, for testing purposes), when the user has spelled the required words it is supposed to send them back to the level select activity and unlock the level 2 button. This is the code for the second activity that checks they have spelled the words and then updates the level they are at on Parse.com before returning them to the level select activity.

```
    if (count == 1){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Wordbank");
        query2.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    objects.get(0).put("level", ++intValue);
                    objects.get(0).saveInBackground();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizLevelSelect.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

All of this works fine except when the user returns to the level select activity, the level 2 button does not become enabled, however if I press back on my phone and then go back into the level select activity it does become enabled. I am assuming this is because when the second activity returns the user to the level select activity the onResume() method is not being run, I have also tried onStart() and onRestart() but neither worked. I know it has something to do with the life cycle of my activities but I dont understand why I have to back out of the activity and then go back into it for the onResume method to run, I thought it ran everytime regardless.

Comment: Did you try to use ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Wordbank");

Comment: you are not doing anything with the level once you obtain it, though

Comment: shouldn't that be `ParseQuery.getQuery(Wordbank.class);`?

Comment: don't you get an exception in the `done` callback?

Comment: @njzk2 I have edited my question to show what I am doing with the level. I tried ParseQuery.getQuery(Wordbank.class); but it says unresolved symbol Wordbank.

Comment: I have completely re-written my question because what I originally thought the problem was actually wasn't the problem. Sorry to those who were trying to help.